# Tensorflow train Model on Server

Tags: android, machine-learning, tensorflow

I need to perform some Machine Learning with data I collected in Android.

I collect some data in an android app, store it in shared preferences and if users clicks a button some prediction based on this data should be displayed.
Therefore, I have to perform some Machine Learning algorithm.

I thought about using Tensorflow.
But according to the Tensorflow Android Tutorial, I need a **pre-trained model**, which I don’t have because I don’t have any saved data.

I think it should be possible to use Tensorflow on a server.
Is it possible to:
Send the collected data from the smartphone to the server?
Train a model on the server?

If the user clicks the predict button, prediction should be done according to the trained model on the server?

Or is there any other way of doing this, or using some other machine learning library on Android (except weka)

Thanks.

Comment: What type of data are you dealing with?

Comment: Data collected from other apps, like heartrate, and also social media data from facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this [post](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning/blob/master/README.md#java-deep-learning) and [here](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/12/machine-learning-data-science-apis.html) for libraries and give a read to this [article](https://jalammar.github.io/Supercharging-android-apps-using-tensorflow/).

Lastly, go through this [sample code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) by Google itself on **Android** using **TF**.

Almost in all cases the training of data is done in the server and the model is used to predict data in the smartphone. You can use cloud services like [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/getting-started/) by Amazon, Azure or others to train your model.

Firstly, you need to collect data and send it to the server repeatedly (more the data, the better). This should be the training period wherein you have to use real time data the user is most likely to use.

Once enough data is collected, you can train the model. Then use this for prediction while continuously collecting data from the user. Then once in a while, train your model again. This will improve your prediction. This way you train and use the model in a cycle.

Comment: thanks I know this sample code by Google. But they are using a pre-trained model. Actually I only find examples (also using Tensorflow on a server) using a pre-trianed model. I want to train a model either on the smartphone or on the server every time data is sent.

Comment: Answer updated. Train model on the server. You don't train every time when data is sent to the server. It should be inversely proportional to your usage. At first training should be frequent. Once data gets large(really large) enough, the rate of training is reduced.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I have another question. I am fairly new to Android, Tensorflow etc. So this means it is possible to use Tensorflow on Azure, AWS? I can send my sollected Data to the server, train the model or the graph tensorflow needs, retrain this graph and use it for prediction? Because I have looked at for tutorials, and every time I only find examples where first a model/graph is trained, and this model/graph is used to retrain the model. Which I can't do because I don't have any data now.

Comment: Well, yes it is possible. Secondly, you have to train your model once you start collecting data. Once enough data is collected, then you can train and retrain your model for better prediction.